# sifr alternate text always displays

Tags: sifr

Using sifr3-r436. First page load of seems fine. Reload page and sifr-alternate text always displays resulting in a double headline, one Flash text one HTML. Any ideas?

Please see example here:
http://v3.kevincarrollkatalyst.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

It was some kind of CSS problem. Rolling the sifr css properties into my screen and print style sheets fixed the problem.

Comment: Could you not explain this a little better? Should you have had some CSS to hide the sifr-alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's your SIFR-stylesheet that isn't loaded properly. Please ensure that the path is correct: